# Iptables forward traffic to gost transparent proxy

Tags: iptables, proxy

[Gost](https://docs.ginuerzh.xyz/gost/en/) is a networking module which allows you to treat it as many things including a transparent proxy.

On their page regarding [transparent proxies](https://docs.ginuerzh.xyz/gost/en/redirect/) you can see that there is a way to write iptables rules such that udp traffic is forwarded to the transparent proxy.

However their iptables rules seem to incorporate tproxy and this is where my issue occurs. What I'm trying to achieve is that I want *all* udp traffic forwarded to gost - not just traffic specific to a particular port. However on their iptables rules they seem to specify a rule using tproxy in which packets are marked only when sent to a particular port number.

I guess my question is there any way to accomplish what I'm trying to do? That is, forward all udp traffic to the gost transparent proxy using iptables?

For those of you who do not want to visit the links here is what the iptables rules are that were written out on the gost website:

```
iptables -t mangle -N GOST
iptables -t mangle -N GOST_LOCAL

iptables -t mangle -A GOST -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A GOST -d 127.0.0.0/8 -p udp -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A GOST -d 192.168.0.0/16 -p udp -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A GOST -p udp -j TPROXY --on-port 12345 --on-ip 0.0.0.0 --tproxy-mark 1

iptables -t mangle -A GOST_LOCAL -d 255.255.255.255/32 -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A GOST_LOCAL -d 192.168.0.0/16 -p udp -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A GOST_LOCAL -d 1.2.3.4/32 -p udp -j RETURN
iptables -t mangle -A GOST_LOCAL -p udp -j MARK --set-mark 1

iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j GOST
iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j GOST_LOCAL
```

Then they seem to have some rule regarding a routing table. I'm not sure what that is but I will include it just to make sure that I'm thorough.

```
ip rule add fwmark 1 table 100
ip route add local 0.0.0.0/0 dev lo table 100
```